# scope.watch is not running on inactive tabs

Tags: angularjs

I am running an angular app. when i get socket message i need to do some animation in svg file using angular. Now I am using scope.watch method.whenever got some changes in variable it will watch an running the *svg* object. it's working fine. but the problem is i run my code and then switch to another tab, wait a few seconds and go back, the animation continues at the point it was when you switched to the other tab. what is the issue with scope.watch.Please give me a solution for this problem. or what happening when I move to another tab

my example is code as follows:

```
myapp.directive('directive', function($http,$templateCache,$compile,$interval) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myvar:'=myvar'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('myvar', function(newValue, oldValue){
                element.html( '<g transform="translate(scope.myvar)"' +'>'

                    +'<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1528 684"><ellipse class="cls-car-1" cx="898.36" cy="479.67" rx="14.33" ry="20.5"/><rect class="cls-car-2" x="881.69" y="498.25" width="26.75" height="61" rx="7" ry="7"/><path class="cls-car-3" d="M917.61,466.08c4.67-4.67,14.67-15.33,14.67,5.33s5.33,65.33,0,64-24.67,7.33-24.67-3.33S917.61,466.08,917.61,466.08Z"/><path class="cls-car-3" d="M1019.61,483.42c4.67-4.67,14.67-15.33,14.67,5.33s5.33,65.33,0,64-24.67,7.33-24.67-3.33S1019.61,483.42,1019.61,483.42Z"/></svg>'
                    +'</g>');
                return $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample code for that?

Comment: i have put my directive code.this is the simple code to move svg image using transform method.

Comment: you display svg animation when web service call fired? right?

Comment: For that you need to make 2 service which is help you to show and hide svg animation. You have to call show() when api call init and hide() when api response comes

Comment: let me know  the use of show() and hide() here.i need to move the object whenever socket message come.now it's moving fine. but i really don't know what happens when i switch to another tab

Comment: you also display loader when socket message comes?

Comment: no.i don't want to display any loader